# ssl secure when i add HTTP(S) on azure?

Tags: .net, azure, ssl

i am quite new to ssl... and now i want to create a ssl on a website on the cloud service like azure. However if we going with normal way like upload our own certificate to azure, it will be a secure channel. However i realized even i dont upload my own certificate, when i key in extra S on the http, it can become a secure channel too.

the following is my url

http://cardmm.azurewebsites.net/

however i didnt upload anything and just key in s to become https

https://cardmm.azurewebsites.net/

it become secure channel.[image]

i want to ask, does this ssl will be secure? if secure, why people want to upload their own certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to ask, does this ssl will be secure?

Yes, it is secure. The key thing to understand is the SSL certificate is issued to `*.azurewebsites.net` domain and it is available to you for free as long as you are accessing your site via `yoursite.azurewebsites.net`. If you click on `lock` icon in the address bar, you will see the details of the certificate.

> if secure, why people want to upload their own certificate.

The reason you would want to bring your own certificate is because (as I mentioned above) is that the SSL certificate is tied to `*.azurewebsites.net` and not your domain (e.g. yourwebsite.com). If you want users to access your website securely using your domain name, you will need to get a SSL certificate for your domain and upload it.